# Launch Google Authenticator and register secret Xamarin Forms iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-authenticator

I am trying to setup an entry in Google Authenticator from my Xamarin Forms app by launching using the URI `otpauth://totp/...` but I am having some trouble opening the app.

Specifically, it opens the iOS 15 password manager (even though I did not launch using `apple-otpauth://`).

I have registered otpauth and totp inside info.plist under LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, and my URI looks like this: `otpauth://totp/{company}:{name}?secret={Secret}&issuer={company}`.

It works on Android just right, but on iOS I cannot get it to work. I could open the Google Authenticator app using `googleauthenticator://` but I cannot send the parameters (It just opens the app).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You can try xamarin auth https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=ios

Comment: Having exactly the same problem, were you able to resolve it?